# Is it possible to reopen a suspended app after a time delay in Swift?

Tags: swift, swift2

I am using the following code to suspend the app.

```
UIControl().sendAction(Selector("suspend"), to: UIApplication.sharedApplication(), forEvent: nil)
    do {
        print("suspended")
    } catch _ {
        print("unable")
    }
```

I was wondering is it possible to reopen the app after a certain time delay. Following code works for performing an action after time delay. But I don't know how to reopen the app at that time interval

```
let seconds = 300.0
    let delay = seconds * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)  // nanoseconds per seconds
    let dispatchTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay))
    dispatch_after(dispatchTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        print("time delay")
    })
```

Comment: You can't, in suspended app the code does not runs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's is not possible and apps with such kind of "functionality" will be rejected by Appstore ;)

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/StartingStopping.html

### Always Be Prepared to Stop

**An iOS app never displays a Close or Quit option**

When people switch away from your app, iOS multitasking transitions it to the background and replaces its UI with the UI of the new app. To prepare for this situation, your app should:

- **Save user data as soon as possible and as often as reasonable**. Do
  this because an app in the background can be told to exit or
  terminate at any time.
- **Save the current state when stopping at the finest level of detail possible.** In this way, people don’t lose their
  context when they switch back to your app. For example, if your app
  displays scrolling data, save the current scroll position. You can
  learn more about efficient ways to preserve and restore your app’s
  state in Preserving Your App’s Visual Appearance Across Launches.

Some apps may need to keep running in the background while users run another app in the foreground. For example, users might want to keep listening to the song that’s playing in one app while they’re using a different app to check their to-do list or play a game. Learn how to handle multitasking correctly and gracefully in Multitasking.

**Never quit an iOS app programmatically**. People tend to interpret this as a crash. If something prevents your app from functioning as intended, you need to tell users about the situation and explain what they can do about it.